# ajaxComplete not firing to stop script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm stuck on a making a simple loading function for an AJAX request. AJAX is still pretty new to me, so I'm sure I'm just doing something dumb!

ajaxStart fires and starts loading the spinner.gif, but ajaxComplete doesn't fire and the gif keeps on spinning even after the second page's results have loaded after a delay of 1 second. Jquery is loaded and the ajax load of the second page works fine - its just stopping this loading gif from playing once the load function is done! Any ideas anyone? Thanks!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document).ajaxStart(function(load_a){
    $("#wait_a").css("display", "block");
});


$(document).ajaxComplete(function(load_a){
    $("#wait_a").css("display", "none");
});


var load_a = function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#ajax_content_a').load('http://localhost/a.php');},1000);
        alert(exception);
}


load_a();


});
</script>

<div id="ajax_content_a">Loading...</div>
<div id="wait_a" style="display:none;width:120px;height:120px;border:0px;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;padding:2px;"><img src='http://localhost/loading_spinner.gif' width="120" height="120" /></div>
```

Comment: are you sure you should wrap `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxComplete` in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: your example is working fine.. here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7q94fuzw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does not solve your problem (well, it might actually. But it won't solve the root of the problem), it's very likely that the reason `ajaxComplete` is never hit is because something is failing before that. To make sure, add the below snippet:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    console.log(event)
    console.log(jqxhr)
    console.log(settings)
    console.log(thrownError)
    alert('Ouch, ajax failed: ' + thrownError);
    $("#wait_a").css("display", "none");
});
```

Inspect the console for detailed error message.

`ajaxComplete` should normally be invoked after an error, but not if the code halts because of the error.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! There was an error in a script on the page being loaded with ajax that I hadn't spotted.