# ajaxComplete event not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would love to give a minimal example of this breaking, but it's some code I'm adding to work with my Thinkific course player so that's impossible. This code never fires, even though there are multiple ajax requests going out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        console.log('triggered ajax');
   });
});
```

But this works just fine:

```
setTimeout(() => {
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        console.log('triggered ajax');
   });
}, 200);
```

Can anyone think of a reason that this event isn't getting triggered, or how I can go about troubleshooting it? `setTimeout()` is really hacky. I've also attempted to build this listener with XMLHttpRequest, but that won't work for my use case because I need access to outgoing headers that ajax provides in `settings`.

EDIT: Current More Reliable Solution

Instead of just hoping 200ms is the correct time to wait, I decided to use setInterval to check if the ajaxComplete event is triggering my code.

```
function checkAjax() {
    var events = $._data(document, "events");
    if (events.ajaxComplete) {
        clearInterval(ajaxInterval);
        console.log('ajax attached!');
        return;
    }
    console.log('waiting');
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        console.log('triggered ajax');
    });
}
var ajaxInterval = setInterval(checkAjax, 200);
```

Comment: is there a reason behind putting the first snippet inside `document ready`?

Comment: No reason, actually. Just something I thought I'd try. It fails either way.

Comment: My guess is that you have multiple copies of jQuery being included in your page. Don't do that

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if the reason for this strange behavior is that the thinkific course player is an SPA. Is there another event dispatched by a typical SPA that I can wait for?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following snippet:

credit to: [ajaxComplete not firing to stop script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218310/ajaxcomplete-not-firing-to-stop-script)

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    console.log(event)
    console.log(jqxhr)
    console.log(settings)
    console.log(thrownError)
    alert('Ouch, ajax failed: ' + thrownError);
    $("#wait_a").css("display", "none");
});
```

see if its failing in anyway, also you could add an extend method and look to capture the  success:  error: beforeSend: complete, see an example here: [Can I listen to a specific element on ajaxComplete instead of 'document'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930653/can-i-listen-to-a-specific-element-on-ajaxcomplete-instead-of-document) , it may be firing the call but failing have you check thew browser network logs to see if it makes the request ?

---

**EDIT**

---

Could you try this as an alternative to setinterval

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(function() {
      $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
        console.log('triggered ajax');
      });
      $(this).dequeue();
    })
  });
```

Sorry I know i'm probably not been helpful just trying a process of elimination

I hope this helps

Comment: No errors reported. The requests are logged in Network tab of DevTools.

Comment: And I can't extend the ajax call method because I don't have control of it, the reason for the listener.

Comment: this is a bit of a long shot but what if you try dding it inside ```$(window).on('load', function (e) { ...... })``` or ``` window.addEventListener('load', function () {......  ``` the reason being that document load fires when the dom is loaded but window on load fires when the whole content is loaded like page contain images,css etc. As the code works when you use a timer makes me wonder if its only binding after everything has loaded fully

Comment: Thanks. It was promising, and seemed to work the first time, but on page reload it works every 6th or 7th time.

Comment: thats interesting, did you add it outside of the jquery document load/ ready event ?

Comment: yes, I had it originally outside the ready wrapper and it was working fine. Then something changed and it stopped loading. So strange the way it loads great if it waits a bit.

Comment: did it make a difference if you used $(window).on('load'  or window.addEventListener('load',  ? The fact that you say it worked first time and then 6th/7th time surgest somthing is loading after the page load or that the order in witch things are loading in is playing a part, this is a bit of a long shot again but could you try moving the script to the END of the page, having it in the header or even the body can make a difference as it hold the browser up whilst if gets the scripts , also I have posed an edit to my original answer could you give that a try see if that works too plz ?

Comment: also you said something changed, don't happen to know what as the key probably lies there ? if you use source control or can revert changes to see at what point it stopped working you could find what what broke it and then hopefully understand why

Comment: OK, the `$(this).delay(1000)` code works 100% of the time. But neither of the `$(window).on('load'` or `window.addEventListener('load',` work consistently. They're about the same. I didn't change my code at all, I'm just speculating that something changed in the Thinkific code.

Comment: ah i see, might be worth asking them for support ? I suepct they might be loading in their own scripts, in the browser network are they loading any script in that might cause issues, say google analytics?  did moving the script to the end of the page help at all, to be fair that was a long shot at best, at least with ```$(this).delay(1000)``` that's a cleaner solution to setinterval as only runs the once

Comment: It's loading in the footer right now, can't move it. FWIW I was using `setTimeout(()` which is a one time thing.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: oh yes sorry thought you were using setinterval, its strange you have to delay the script, something somewhere is causing that and if its not something you added it must be the site that hosts it hence the suggestion of asking them.... are you able to post a link to it could always take a look see if I can spot anything ?  could try adding ```$.noConflict();``` before the on load just to rule out conflicting JQ library's,  Sorry I don't think I have been much help,

Comment: You've given me some great things to try, so that's a big help. I appreciate your willingness to give me ideas.

Comment: thats ok sorry I couldn't help more